# Roblox - FE part creator script not working

Tags: lua, filtering, roblox

I'm making an FE game in Roblox, and I'm having a problem with an FE code inside a tool. Can I get help?

Inside the tool:

```
script.Parent.Activated:Connect(function()
game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage"):FindFirstChild('TS'):FireServer(game.Players.LocalPlayer)
end)
```

Inside the Event script

```
local eventplace = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
eventplace:FindFirstChild('TS').OnServerEvent:connect(function(player)
local rangeball = Instance.new('Part',workspace)
    local rangemesh = Instance.new("SpecialMesh",rangeball)
    rangemesh.MeshType = Enum.MeshType.Sphere
    rangeball.Size = Vector3.new(7,7,7)
    player.Character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 0
    rangeball.Parent = workspace
end)
```

Comment: Provide more info (detailed error messages etc). You need to be as thorough as possible.

Comment: I don't get any error messages, the code just doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the Remote "TS" in ReplicatedStorage before?

Also, another thing:

When you use :FireServer(), the player/client argument will be automatically passed, so there is no need to do :FireServer(game.Players.LocalPlayer), because the remote event would recive two arguments, both being the client/player.

The script you used in the tool, is a LocalScript. You should instead use non-locals (or Scripts).

And also,

When you use game.Players.LocalPlayer in a localscript, a exploiter can change the name of game.Players locally, which in result would break your script.

To fix that, you'd need variables.

In the tool script:

```
local tool = script.Parent;

tool.Activated:connect(function();
    local rangeball = Instance.new("Part", workspace); -- Since you put ', workspace' the Part will automatically be child of the Workspace. If you did Instance.new("Part", workspace.idk) it will set the parent of the part to workspace.idk, and if workspace.idk doens't exist, it will throw out a error.
    rangeball.Shape = "Sphere"; -- We can just use 'Shape' property to replace sphere meshes!
    -- No need to do 'rangeball.Parent = workspace' because with simply doing 'Instance.new("Part", workspace)' you do the same function because Instance.new takes two arguments (class, parent)!
    pcall(function() -- We use 'pcall()' here to prevent errors.
        tool.Parent.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 0; -- Set the Player's WalkSpeed.
    end);
end);
```

With that code, you can freely remove the Event script!

If you're going to use Events, make sure that the Event script is located inside ServerScriptService, that way it is safer, and runs correctly. Remember, scripts only run in ReplicatedFirst, ServerScriptService, Workspace, and a few others.

Hope my answer helps you.

Also, one last thing, welcome to stack overflow!